# Как удалить строки в CSV?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

В общем возникла проблема. У меня есть большой csv файл с колонкой, data и есть список из значений. Мне нужно записать в другой csv-файл всю строку из файла, если в колонке data, есть значение из списка.

```
with open('arm.csv', newline='') as File:
with open('wdays_data.csv', mode='w') as wdays:
    reader = csv.reader(File)
    for row in reader:
        if row[0] in weekend_days:
            writer = csv.writer(wdays, delimiter=',')
            writer.writerows(row[0])
```

Вот как пробовал я.

Вывод **row**:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не до конца понял в чем вопрос...в заголовке про удаление строк, в тексте про создание нового CSV, который вы вроде как и делаете сами...а в чем проблема то сама? что вас не устраивает? что не так работает?

Comment: а... и вправду. Что-то я совсем поплыл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import csv

weekend_days = [
    '2020-03-12',
    '2020-03-13'
]

with open('import.csv', newline='') as source:
    reader = csv.DictReader(source)
    with open('export.csv', mode='w', encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as destination:
#                      Используйте эту кодировку ^^^
#                      если собираетесь открывать в Excel

        writer = csv.DictWriter(destination, dialect=csv.unix_dialect, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(
            filter(lambda x: x.get('date') not in weekend_days, reader)
        ) #                         ^^^^ Вот тут название поля с датой
```

Comment: вы гений. спасибо!